# SDL2 Load embedded binary

Tags: c, sdl-2

Hi I'm trying to load an embedded png with SDL2. I only managed to create the file before but didn't load it directly. I tried to put the
_binary_flower_png_ in the IMG_LoadTexture but it didnt work .Here is how far I come(It works fine, but I dont wont to create a file)

```
 #include <stdlib.h>

#include <stdio.h>

#include <SDL2/SDL.h>

#include <SDL2/SDL_image.h>

extern const char _binary_flower_png_start[];

extern const char _binary_flower_png_end[];

extern const int _binary_flower_png_size;

int main()
{

SDL_Event event;
    SDL_Renderer *renderer = NULL;
    SDL_Texture *texture = NULL;
    SDL_Window *window = NULL;
        SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_TIMER | SDL_INIT_VIDEO);
    SDL_CreateWindowAndRenderer(
        500, 500,
        0, &window, &renderer
    );

    //File create

FILE *f = fopen("flower.png", "wb");
    fwrite(_binary_flower_png_start, &_binary_flower_png_end, 
    &_binary_flower_png_start, f);
    fclose(f);
    printf("File created");

    //Load here

    IMG_Init(IMG_INIT_PNG);
    texture = IMG_LoadTexture(renderer, "flower.png");

//Render

    while (1) {
        SDL_RenderCopy(renderer, texture, NULL, NULL);
        SDL_RenderPresent(renderer);
        if (SDL_PollEvent(&event) && event.type == SDL_QUIT)
            break;
    }
    SDL_DestroyTexture(texture);
    IMG_Quit();
    SDL_DestroyRenderer(renderer);
    SDL_DestroyWindow(window);
    SDL_Quit();
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;


}
```

Comment: You need `IMG_LoadTexture_RW` along with `SDL_RWFromConstMem`.

Answer (score 0):

The way you load any resource in SDL 2.0 (whether it is from SDL_image, SDL_mixer, SDL_ttf, et. al.) is by using an [SDL_RWops](https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_RWops) pointer to that memory.

To load a .png file from a memory buffer:

```
extern uint8_t *buffer; // presumably, this holds the bytes of a .png file  
extern int cbBuffer; // the size of the .png data buffer

SDL_Surface *loadPng(void) {
  SDL_Surface *result = NULL;
  SDL_RWops *stream = SDL_RWFromConstMem(buffer, cbBuffer);
  if (stream == NULL) {
    // error handling for failure - call SDL_GetError()
  }
  else {
    result = IMG_LoadPNG_RW(stream); // does not free the source stream
    SDL_RWclose(stream);
  }
  return result; // may be NULL - caller should check
}
```

Alternatively, you could use the [SDL_RWFromFile()](https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_RWFromFile) function to load the .png file, if it isn't already loaded into an external buffer:

```
SDL_Surface *loadPng(const char *path) {
  SDL_Surface *result = NULL;
  SDL_RWops *stream = SDL_RWFromFile(path, "rb");
  if (stream == NULL) {
    // error handling for failure - call SDL_GetError()
  }
  else {
    result = IMG_LoadPNG_RW(stream); // does not free the source stream
    SDL_RWclose(stream);
  }
  return result; // may be NULL - caller should check
}
```